# Android/EVO bike mount recommendations

Tags: road-bike, accessories, handlebars, smartphone-mount

Does anyone have experience mounting an EVO phone on the handlebars of a road bike?

Comment: Is an EVO phone a specific type of Android phone?

Comment: Yes Neilfein. From what I gather, we can name off every phone on this site.

Comment: Might be worth changing it from "Evo" to "large smartphone" to make it more generic...

Comment: Give that it is not safe to touch or look at a phone while cycling, I don’t think mounting a phone on a handle bar is a safe thing to do.

Comment: @Ian: There's apps for many smartphones that could be useful while cycling.  Especially GPS and cyclometer type apps. You wouldn't be "using a phone", you'd be glancing down at a display of where you are, how fast you're going, or something like that...

Comment: @Ian Agree with @freiheit. It's no more dangerous than a speedometer or GPS.

Comment: Might be some compatible suggestions here: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/725/iphone-4-bike-mount-recommendations (you already knew that, but might help somebody who visits this question later)

Comment: I think we can answer this question with the assumption that the question author wants to use the phone as a GPS and bike computer while riding, which seems fine to me. @wdypdx22, you might consider making the question more general, to cover more types of Android phones; you're more likely to get answers that way. (If nobody here has an answer, you can *also* try asking at android.stackexchange.com.)

Comment: @neilfein - Why limit it to "android"? The question (and there's another about an iPhone) relates to slab-like smartphones. Given how much one is worth ($400 and up) I wouldn't want to put it on the handlebars... (I have a Windows Phone 7 - similar size, spec, etc)

Comment: @Murph - Garmin has a few products designed to be mounted on handlebars with a price tag upwards of US $350. So, instead of buying another gizmo, I'd gladly mount my smartphone there.

Comment: @Ian - "Give that it is not safe to touch or look at a phone while cycling, I don’t think mounting a phone on a handle bar is a safe thing to do." - I've been touching and looking at my heart rate monitor and cycle computer for years now. How is a smartphone any different?

Comment: Yes, but those gizmos, I have one, are *designed* to live on a bike exposed to the elements.

Comment: It's possible this question could get some good answers on [android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: -1. Uneasy with bike, closed-obfuscated blob (to some extent) and complicated UI. @Kosh: see how imperfect things are, surely, there must be better options ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always try making your own. There are lots of different ideas for designs over at [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/pages/search/search.jsp?cx=partner-pub-1783560022203827%3Anpr2q7v5m6t&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=phone+handlebar+mount) the one below uses the bracket off an old reflector plus a phone holder (ie for mounting your phone on a car dashboard) screwed to it. More details [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Quick-Dirty-Bicycle-Phone-Mount/). I particularly like the rubber bands for extra security. My main worry would be the rain though and the danger of getting the phone wet (but then I do live near Manchester in the UK).

[image: smart phone handlebar mount]

Comment: Would a "ziploc" type bag around the phone help with the wet issue? (sorry, don't know the generic term for that style of plastic bag)

Comment: I'd call them food bags, sandwich bags or freezer bags. It might keep the phone dry but would probably make it nigh on impossible to read the screen. At which point the whole reason for mounting the phone on the handlebars goes out the window.

Comment: To deal with weather, I've seen a variety of purpose-built zip-top plastic bags that are supposed to keep the touchscreen usable, like http://www.rei.com/product/808607